# Is there a faster algorithm than $O(n^2)$ for calculating "cofactors" $C_k = \prod\limits_{j\neq k}(c_k - c_j)$?

Tags: polynomials, algorithms, numerical-methods

Is there a faster algorithm than $O(n^2)$ for calculating "cofactors" $C_k = \prod\limits_{j\neq k}(c_k - c_j)$ ? (presumably $O(n \log_2 n)$ if one exists)

In other words, if I have factors $\mathbf c = \begin{bmatrix}2 & 3 & 5 & 7\end{bmatrix}$, I want to calculate

- $C_0 = (2-3) \times (2-5) \times (2-7) = -15$
- $C_1 = (3-2) \times (3-5) \times (3-7) = 8$
- $C_2 = (5-2) \times (5-3) \times (5-7) = -12$
- $C_3 = (7-2) \times (7-3) \times (7-5) = 40$

With a small number like 4 entries I would just calculate the results the straightforward way, but I'm wondering if I have hundreds or thousands of entries if there is a fast way like the FFT. The coefficients $c_k$ aren't necessarily integers and could even be complex numbers -- but they are distinct.

This relates to the polynomial $p(x) = \prod\limits_k(x - c_k)$ since $C_k = \left. p'(x)\right|_{x=c_k}$. But I'm not sure that helps; with polynomials of large degree, I am not sure how to evaluate polynomial derivatives in a way that does not suffer from numerical errors. (except for Chebyshev polynomials)

Comment: Some software may be able to calculate $p'(x)$ at lots of points, more quickly than the long list of products.

Comment: yeah, vectorization is another option. (I'm using numpy in my case.) But the polynomial coefficients are huge and are ill-conditioned; I have to work with the roots directly in order to keep numerical errors low.

Comment: What Michael was on about is multipoint evaluation using FFT polynomial products in polynomial division which gives $O(n\log n)$ complexity.

Comment: could you elaborate?